# Catchall term for "Junior", "Senior", "the late", "widow", and the like?

Tags: single-word-requests, names

I'm analyzing a bunch of late 16th century Hungarian names, and I need a word for those extra bits that sometimes get appended to names, like *junior, senior, the late* and the like. My "working title" has been *prefix* (because they generally come first in Hungarian), but that's inaccurate, because they're not actually attached to anything. I thought of *appelation*, but that's just another term for "name", and as such is too broad. Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it can be either a prefix or a suffix, then it is an **[affix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affix#Noun)**. "**Name affix**" would cover both bases.

Answer (score 6):

In English "Jr." and "Sr." and "M.D." and the like are called *[name suffixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_%28name%29)*. I don't think "widow" is ever used that way, though. And "the late" is simply an adjectival form, not a title.

Comment: What's done in English names is pretty irrelevant to my question, unfortunately. And I don't think "name suffixes" is accurate, because as far as I know suffixes need to actually be attached to something, like _-ful_ or _-less_.

Comment: @JPmiaou: As the link shows, "name suffix" is an actual term. In many form fields, in fact, the label  for that extra name component is simply "Suffix".

Comment: "Widow" is occasionally used as if it were a title: *"the widow Johnson"*.

Comment: @JPmiaou: Wait, are you saying your question is actually off-topic?

Comment: I've only ever heard these referred to as a suffix. If you're going to say suffix can't be right because it should be attached to a word, then you shouldn't be using prefix either, really. Agree with dmckee about the use of 'widow' though.

Comment: @Robusto: no, it's not off-topic, because I need an English word for something. That something just happens to _not_ be English names.

Comment: @Loquacity: yes, I know prefix has the same problem as suffix (lack of attachment); hence my question.

Comment: I've checked everything I could think of, and none of them came up with anything better than _prefix_. (The suggested _suffix_ definitely doesn't work for the category.) The linked Wikipedia page uses _prefix_ for "Dr." and "Atty", in fact. Thanks anyway, everyone!

Comment: Affix is the hypernym for "prefix or suffix".

Answer (score 6):

I think an adequate word could be [epithet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/epithet):

> any word or phrase applied to a person or thing to describe an actual or attributed quality: “Richard the Lion-Hearted” is an epithet of Richard I.

Answer (score 5):

In some contexts I've used *honorific* for a prefix and *title* for a suffix.

Answer (score 2):

You could call them *name modifiers.* That's kind of broad (as it seems as though it should also include epithets like *Ivan the Terrible*), but I can't think of any better terms.

Comment: I'm already using "modifier" elsewhere (as a catchall term for things that, well, modify the broader patterns), but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

"title" is the closest you will find, I think. In English references, it's called the suffix, but as you have shown, that is a language-centric designation.

Richard's "epithet" would be "the Lionheart" because his PR popularized it. His title (in our context) is "II", being automatically given to the second king of England named Richard.

Cheers