# Is there a specific term used to describe the "Jr." following a person's name?

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the name John J Doe Jr.  If John is the first name, J is the middle initial, & Doe is the last name, what is Jr.?  I checked with Webster years ago and they could not find a specific name.

Comment: That would mean "Junior", with a father bearing the same first and middle names. (John J senior)

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28560/catchall-term-for-junior-senior-the-late-widow-and-the-like

Answer (score 9):

It is a ***generational title/suffix***:

> Generational suffixes are used to distinguish persons who share the same name within a family. A generational suffix can be used informally (for disambiguation purposes, or as nicknames) and is often incorporated in legal documents.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_(name)#Generational_titles)</sub>

Comment: These generational designations are much less common in Britain, where it is considerably less usual to give a child exactly the same name(s) as his or her parent.

Comment: @WS2: Do you have any numbers for that? It seems pretty rare in the US.

Comment: @Charles No I'm afraid I don't. But I don't know of anyone of my own generation who has named their child directly after themselves.

Comment: Dale Earnhardt Jr. Jr. is a good example

Comment: @WS2: I had a schoolmate named for his father, but I don't know whether they had the same middle name and he certainly didn't go by "Jr".

Comment: @WS2: Generational usage aside, historically, Royals use the Roman numeral versions all the time (albeit, it is more of an incarnation number rather than a generational thing).

Comment: @jxh Perhaps truer to say that 'historians *et al*' use a Roman numbering system for monarchs. But anyone who turned up for work the first day with the name of Henry Arthur Bloggs VIII, would be somewhat open to ridicule, I fear. It reminds me of Hermans Hermits and *I'm Henery the Eighth I am*. Anyone remember how it goes?

Comment: @WS2: That is something I never learned in school (not that I was taught much about the English monarchs in America other their relative importance and years of their reign). I always thought the monarchs decided the complete moniker, the suffix included.

Comment: @Charles - It is common enough in the U.S.